# libssl.so.1.1 not found when running anchor test in Kali Linux

Tags: anchor, solana-cli, cargo

I'm getting the following messages and error when running `anchor test` in Kali Linux:

```
anchor test                                                                                         
BPF SDK: /home/kali/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.9.5/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf
cargo-build-bpf child: rustup toolchain list -v
cargo-build-bpf child: cargo +bpf build --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --release
/home/kali/.rustup/toolchains/bpf/bin/cargo: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm using the versions:

```
solana-cli 1.9.5
cargo and rustc 1.68.0
anchor-cli 0.26.0
node 16.19.1
openssl 3.0.8
```

I'm running the test in the sample project created with `anchor init`.
Tried installing an Ubuntu version of `libssl` but it didn't work.
Already installed `libssl-dev`, which is in the folder `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3`, but the problem still persists.

Any suggestion?
TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try downgrading solana-cli to a stable version with `sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.14.10/install)"`

Edit: This should probably have come first, but re-install openssl with:

```
wget http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.17_amd64.deb
```

and then:

```
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.17_amd64.deb
```

Source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72133316/libssl-so-1-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work, @Ademola :  

`anchor test. 
Warning: cargo-build-bpf is deprecated. Please, use cargo-build-sbf`. 
`cargo-build-bpf child: /home/kali/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/cargo-build-sbf --arch bpf`. 
`info: uninstalling toolchain 'bpf'`. 
`info: toolchain 'bpf' uninstalled`. 
`/home/kali/.rustup/toolchains/bpf/bin/cargo: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. 
Do you know any other thing that could cause this error?

Comment: I updated my answer